# Cracking RSA with small plaintext

Tags: rsa, attack

I read a CTF writeup about cracking 4 primes RSA numbers from [here](https://blog.cryptohack.org/cryptoctf2020#three-ravens):
Given $p, q, r,$ and $p+q+r$ are prime numbers.

> The challenge encrypts the flag with a modulus $N=(p∗q∗r)∗(p+q+r)$
>
> and gives the output $n=pqr, k=p+q+r$. To totally break the
> cryptosystem, we would want to find the totient of the modulus
> $\varphi(N)=(p−1)(q−1)(r−1)(p+q+r−1)$
>
> but we can simplify this when the encrypted message $m$ is small enough.
> If we have $m<k$, we can instead find $\varphi(k)=k−1$, and find $e^{-1}\bmod{\varphi(k)}$, and
> solve!

But how can they replace $p*q*r*(p+q+r)$ with only $(p+q+r)$ and somebody explains that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have given $c = m^{17} \bmod (N=pqrk)$ with $k = p+q+r$

We can write this as $$m^{17} =  c + \ell (pqr)k$$ for some integer $\ell$.

Now consider this as $$m^{17} =  c + (\ell pqr)k$$

if $m < k$ you can find the $m$ if not information is lost and the answer is not unique.

Comment: can you give an example or explain more the part where you say:
 if not information is lost and the answer is not unique

Comment: Put $t = m+ u\cdot k$ and see.

Comment: i still don't understand why do we need the constraint m < k for this to work

Comment: It will not give the correct answer. you will get it's residue mod $k$ and which one will be the answer. $m+u\cdot k$?